# Converting a list of strings in a numpy array in a faster way

Tags: python, string, list, numpy

`br` is the name of a list of strings that goes like this:

```
['14 0.000000 -- (long term 0.000000)\n',
 '19 0.000000 -- (long term 0.000000)\n',
 '22 0.000000 -- (long term 0.000000)\n',
...
```

I am interested in the first two columns, which I would like to convert to a numpy array.
So far, I've come up with the following solution:

```
x = N.array ([0., 0.])
for i in br:
    x = N.vstack ( (x, N.array (map (float, i.split ()[:2]))) )
```

This results into having a 2-D array:

```
array([[  0.,   0.],
       [ 14.,   0.],
       [ 19.,   0.],
       [ 22.,   0.],
...
```

However, since `br` is rather big (~10^5 entries), this procedure takes some time.
I was wondering, is there a way to accomplish the same result, but in less time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is dramatically faster for me:

```
import numpy as N

br = ['14 0.000000 -- (long term 0.000000)\n']*50000
aa = N.zeros((len(br), 2))

for i,line in enumerate(br):
    al, strs = aa[i], line.split(None, 2)[:2]
    al[0], al[1] = float(strs[0]), float(strs[1])
```

Changes:

- Preallocate the numpy array (this is big). You already know you want a 2-dimensional array with particular dimensions.
- Only split() for the first 2 columns, since you don't want the rest.
- Don't use map(): it's slower than list comprehensions. I didn't even use list comprehensions, since you know you only have 2 columns.
- Assign directly into the preallocated array instead of generating new temp arrays as you iterate.

Comment: aa = numpy.array([x.split(' ',2)[0:2] for x in br], dtype='float')

Comment: Good to know about `enumerate`: I wasn't aware of it! Also thanks @steabert to his contribution. The speeds of both solutions seem quite similar to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to preprocess (with awk for exemple) the list of strings if they come from a file, and use numpy.fromtxt.
If you can't do anything about the way you get this list, you have several possibilities:

- give up. You will run this function once a day. You don't care about speed, and your actual solution is good enough
- write an IO plugin with cython. You have a big potential gain because you will be able to do all the loops in c, and affects directly the values in a big (10^5, 2) numpy ndarray
- try another language to fix your problem. If using languages such as c or haskell, you may use ctypes to call the functions compiled in a dll from python

*edit*

maybe this approach is slightly faster:

```
def conv(mysrt):
    return map(float, mystr.split()[:2])

br_float = map(conv, br)
x = N.array(br_float)
```

Comment: Liked the 'out-of-the-box' thinking!

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```
map (float, i.split()[:2])
```

to

```
map (float, i.split(' ',2)[:2])
```

might result in a slight speedup. Since you only care about first two space-separated items in each line there is no need to split the entire line. The `2` in `i.split(' ',2)` tells `split` to just make a maximum of 2 splits. For example,

```
In [11]: x='14 0.000000 -- (long term 0.000000)\n' 

In [12]: x.split()
Out[12]: ['14', '0.000000', '--', '(long', 'term', '0.000000)']

In [13]: x.split(' ',2)
Out[13]: ['14', '0.000000', '-- (long term 0.000000)\n']
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the second argument of `split`!